# I am getting syntax error "List can not be resolved to a type on statement "

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Any help please? I am a total newbie to Selenium.

```
List<WebElement> elements =
  driver.findElements(By.className("a-size-medium s-inline 
  s-access-title  a-text-normal"));
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and let precise your question.

Answer (score 0):

Either import the packages in which these classes are present, or write the entire path

```
import java.util.List
```

and then use

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal"));
```

or

```
java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal"));
```